# Как сделать запрос к API Яндекс.Расписаний на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, яндекс-расписания

Как сделать запрос к API Яндекс.Расписаний на JavaScript, в документации api есть пример, который хорошо работает при обращении через браузер URL:
[http://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey={мой](http://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/schedule/?apikey=%7B%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9) ключ }&station=s9600213&transport_types=plane&direction=all&date=2023-12-18&event=arrival

Как сделать тоже самое только на JavaScript, заголовки передал, возникает ошибка: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
Пример кода:

```
<script>   
  const requestURL =
    "https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/copyright/?apikey={мой ключ}&format=json";

  function sendRequest(method, url) {
    const headers = {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "мой ключ из ЛК API",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT",
    };
    return fetch(url, {
      method: method,
      headers: headers,
    }).then((response) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        return response.json();
      }
      return response.json().then((error) => {
        const e = new Error("Что-то пошло не так", e);
        e.data = error;
        throw e;
      });
    });
  }

  sendRequest("GET", requestURL)
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
</script>
```

Comment: На будущее: метку [api] употреблять нельзя.

Comment: А разве в тексте ошибки прямым языком не написано что надо сделать?

Comment: Я на 95% уверен что этот APi не предназначен для работы из браузера. А вопрос лучше задать в поддержку https://yandex.ru/dev/rasp/doc/ru/concepts/troubleshooting

Answer (score 1):

Во первых, убираем `?apikey={мой ключ}` т.к в документации к апи указано `Параметр можно не передавать, если ключ доступа указан в заголовке Authorization`

Исправленный код:

```
let requestURL = "https://api.rasp.yandex.net/v3.0/copyright/?format=json"
async function sendRequest(method, url) {
    const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "<token>", // избавляемся от лишних заголовков
    };
    return fetch(url, {
        method: method,
        headers: headers,
    }).then((response) => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json();
        }
    return response.json().then((error) => {
    const e = new Error("Что-то пошло не так", e);
    e.data = error;
    throw e;
});
});
}

sendRequest("GET", requestURL)
.then((data) => console.log(data))
.catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Выводит: (проверил почти со всеми методами), если менять условия в requestURL и при этом не вводить apikey (см. во первых)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставил плюс, однако, следите за речью, пожалуйста.

Comment: из браузера тоже работает?

Comment: @Semen спасибо за ответ, скопировал код вставил свой ключ, по прежнему такая же ошибка. Возможно ли проблема связана со средой откуда производиться запуск? Пробовал live server расширение vscode, так же пробовал запускать на локальном сервере Open server. Откуда исполняется код? В личном кабинете yandex, ключ со статусом активный.

Comment: @Adyss У тебя идет как выделенный сервер? Если да то попробуй добавить "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" к заголовку Headers. У меня все работает но не на вдс.
Также советую еще прочитать статью https://javascript.info/fetch-crossorigin если Header не поможет.

Comment: Как этот ответ отвечает на проблему с CORS?

Comment: `добавить "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" к заголовку Headers` это показатель глубокого непонимания как работает CORS

Comment: Увы, я не профессионал, если Вы знаете, то можете написать свой ответ. Так же я основываюсь только на своем опыте, когда то у меня была такая же ошибка, исправилось это в свою же очередь добавлением `header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");`

Comment: @Semen, только делается это на **сервере**, а не в запросе. А на сервере Яндекса автор очевидно ничего сделать не сможет.